# Audio ebook not working in iBooks

Tags: epub, epub-reader, ios, mac-os

I have created an ebook via the Moby Dick epub example here:

https://github.com/IDPF/epub3-samples

I can open the ebook using iBooks (1.14) on Mac (High Sierra 10.13.4), but I can't get it to play the audio. When I press the volume button with the text "Read Aloud", the volume always goes down to its lowest level and when I turn it back up I still don't hear anything. The ebook itself contains a mp4 file. Why is it not working? Are there any alternative readers for mac? I also couldn't get it to work on iphone, again via ibooks. Is this not supported yet? Is there an alternative app I can try for iphone?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Adobe Digital Editions](https://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/download.html) apps for macOS or iOS. Also check out [Menestrello](https://www.readbeyond.it/menestrello/) and the [free Menestrello media overlay epub3 books](https://www.readbeyond.it/ebooks.html).

If you're a software developer, also check out [Minstrel](https://www.readbeyond.it/minstrel/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try out some alternatives that I found through https://alternatives.co:

1. Kindle for Mac
2. iBooks
3. OverDrive Read
4. JAWS